# OpenGL - Why doesn't my ball move?

Tags: c++, opengl, math, visual-studio-2015

In OpenGL, I'm building a football game that allows you to shoot a ball by first moving height indicators left and right, before shooting based on the indicators when a button is pressed. Here's what it looks like:

[Football Game Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw8rf.jpg)

When these indicators are moved, my ball needs to travel at the height of the vertical indicator (y), and left or right direction if the vertical one (x).

Firstly, here's the code that moves my indicators (which are just textures being drawn in my `RenderScene()` function)

```
void SpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y){

if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) {     // moves the bottom indicator RIGHT
        horizontalBarX += 5.0f;
    }

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) {
        horizontalBarX -= 5.0f;  // moves the bottom indicator LEFT
    }

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP) {    // moves the top indicator UP
        verticalBarY += 5.0f;
        verticalBarX += 1.0f;
    }

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) {  // moves the top indicator DOWN
        verticalBarY -= 5.0f;
        verticalBarX -= 1.0f;
    }
}
```

**Calculations for my football to move**

Now to get my football to move after the indicators have be moved, I need to apply the following calculations to the `x`, `y` and `z` axis of the ball:

> x = sin(theta) * cos (phi) y = cos(theta) * sin(phi) z = cos(theta)
>
> where theta = angle in z-x, and phi = angle in z-y

So with this, I have attempted to get the values of both theta and phi angles first, by simply incrementing them depending on what height indicators you have pressed in the `SpecialKeys()` function:

```
void SpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y){

if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) {     // moves the bottom indicator RIGHT
        horizontalBarX += 5.0f;
        theta += 5;   // Increase theta angle by 5
    }

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) {
        horizontalBarX -= 5.0f;  // moves the bottom indicator LEFT
        theta -= 5;    // Decrease theta angle by 5
    }

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP) {    // moves the top indicator UP
        verticalBarY += 5.0f;
        verticalBarX += 1.0f;
        phi += 5;    // Increase theta angle by 5
    }

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) {  // moves the top indicator DOWN
        verticalBarY -= 5.0f;
        verticalBarX -= 1.0f;   
        phi -= 5;    // Decrease phi angle by 5
    }
}
```

Now that I have the angles, I want to plug in the calculated values into the drawFootball() parameters, which by the way is initially called in my RenderScene function as...

```
drawFootBall(0, 40, 500, 50); // x,.y, z, r
```

...and here's how I'm attempting to launch the ball with the calculations above:

```
void SpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y){

   // indicator if statements just above this line

   if (key == GLUT_KEY_F1) {
        drawFootBall(sin(theta)*cos(phi), cos(theta)*sin(phi), cos(theta), 50);
    }
}
```

But when I go to click the launch button <kbd>F1</kbd>, **nothing happens at all**. Where have I messed up?

**EDIT:**

If it helps, here's my `drawFootball()` function:

```
void drawFootBall(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat r)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    glTranslatef(x,y,z);
    //create ball texture
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[TEXTURE_BALL]);
    //glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColor3f(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    quadricFootball = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadricFootball, GLU_FILL);
    gluQuadricNormals(quadricFootball, GLU_SMOOTH);
    gluQuadricOrientation(quadricFootball, GLU_OUTSIDE);
    gluQuadricTexture(quadricFootball, GL_TRUE);
    gluSphere(quadricFootball, r, 85, 50);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: It's going to be very hard to help you without seeing what drawFootBall() does.

Comment: Hi @Frank, I've edited my question for you showing my drawFootball() function.

Comment: Your angles should be in radians, not degrees. Five radians is almost 360 degrees.

Comment: You're drawing the ball at some place with coordinates between -1 and 1. Are you sure that that's a visible location? (And that your viewpoint isn't inside the sphere?)

Comment: @molbdnilo could you show me what part of the code you mean when you say I'm drawing between -1 and 1?

Comment: @BenTanos `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` are between -1 and 1 for all `x`, and that's what you're using for the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure your `theta` and `phi` are in the right units i.e. Radians. If in degrees convert them to radians by using `sin(theta * PI/180.0f)` and so on, assuming PI is defined.

I believe what you are computing there is a direction vector for the Ball. The `d(x,y,z)` is the direction in which the ball should travel, (assuming there is no gravity or other forces). Its probably the direction in which the ball is kicked.

I think if you simply wanted to move your ball, you need to multiply this direction with a length. Since your ball has a radius of 50 units, try translating to 2 times this radius.

```
glTranslatef(2.0f*r*x,2.0f*r*y,2.0f*r*z);
```

This will move the ball to 2 times its radius in your desired direction.
However you probably want to have some physics to have a more realistic movement.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this makes sense. Just a few quick questions. With this glTranslate, in which function do I place this in (I'm assuming my RenderScene function but just want to be sure). Also, do I basically plug in each calculation to an x,y,z variable and use them in the glTranslate?

Comment: Also, how can I make this translation happen only when the F1 key is pressed?

Comment: Ideally you would draw the ball every frame instead of just when F1 is pressed. Simply store the translation in a variable and increment accordingly or use a flag and translate only if flag is checked.